# Querying a key list and refference Key in google app engine with java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to query objects with a list of keys and a refference key as follows:

```
//s is a datastore key
Query q2 = pm.newQuery(Stream_Result.class,":p.contains(key) && stream == " + KeyFactory.keyToString(s));

ArrayList<List<Stream_Result> stream_r_list = (List<Stream_Result>) q2.execute(Arrays.asList(cr.getStreamResults().toArray()))
```

It works perfectly until a key with the character "-" is introduced.
if s is somthing like ag1zfmVkaW5zdHV0aW9ucg4LEgZTdHJlYW0Y then it executes fine. But if the key is something like ag1zfmVkaW5zdHV0aW9ucg4LEgZTdHJlYW0Y-dIBDA I get an exception:

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$UnsupportedDatastoreFeatureException:

Right side of expression is composed of unsupported components.  Left: org.datanucleus.query.expression.VariableExpression, Op:  - , Right: VariableExpression{dIBDA}
```

How can I work arround this?

Comment: You should not construct query strings by appending parameter values to it. Instead use a query string where you indicate parameters (places), and you execute the query parameterized, passing parameter values to the execute method.

Comment: I have tried that like this 'Query q2 = pm.newQuery(Stream_Result.class);'
'q2.setFilter(":p1.contains(key)");'
'q2.setFilter("stream == streamParam");'
'q2.declareParameters("com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key streamParam");'    'q2.execute(Arrays.asList(cr.getStreamResults().toArray()),s);'
But whenever I do it the I get the error 'Query requires 1 parameters, yet 2 values have been provided'. I dont know what is wrong with that.

Comment: You get the error message: "Query requires 1 parameters, yet 2 values have been provided." because you pass 2 parameters to the `execute()` method: a `List` and the `Key` s; but yet you only declare one `Key` parameter!

Comment: I also need to use the `contains()` method to query against primary keys of the objects from a list of keys as in the code. If I put only the `Key` s in the `execute()` method, I get another error: `Explicit parameters defined for query, yet implicit parameter syntax (":p1") found`

Comment: You should check again the query documentation. There are 2 ways to specify parameters in a query string: by index and by name. It looks you mix the two. You are on the right track, just check the documentation how to specify the parameters exactly.

Comment: I didnt get a solution but tried to query the stream column using the `contain()` method as in the key and it worked perfectly. Thanks alot for the help...